# Wordpress ACF Pro & CPT / User Logged In = User in Field Type

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need a little help, if anyone can!

Using ACF Pro, and CPT, I have made a front end form where an admin can choose a user name and other specific information, then click submit and the post is published.

What I want to do now, is only allow the chosen user to see that post as long as they are logged in. Meaning, the chosen user is logged in and can only see the new post that has their name selected.

Thanks in advance! I’ve tried just about everything.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the post, don't store *just* the username - store the user ID as well as a meta value on the post. Then, for the logged-in user, [get the current user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) get the current user prior to querying your posts, and more specifically, get the user's ID. Then, pass that in your post query to limit the results to just that user's "tagged" posts.

Something like this (assuming we're on an archive, your post type is 'messages'), and you stored the "tagged" user id in a field named `tagged_user_id`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_users_posts' );

function get_users_posts( $query ){
  if( $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'messages' ) && is_user_logged_in() ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'tagged_user_id' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value', $current_user->ID );
  }
}
```

Doing this in your functions.php file, you ensure that any logged-in user on the 'messages' archive page only sees his/her messages. You can adapt it for single-messages as well, and you'll want to handle users who are not logged in as well (I presume).

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for the help, and that does make sense. I will work this into my functions and let you know how I fair. Most appreciated!